# Arrayformula : ranging issue

Tags: arrays, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I am trying to range the Data from the tab "Extracted data" in the tab "Action Items". YoY Change (clicks) column (Action items tab) is taking the data from Clicks Delta (Extracted data tab).

For some reasons, it simply does not range the data in the right way.

I would like to range the data in the following way:

```
YoY Change
0 - Negative
2.5 - No change
5 - Positive
```

I am ranging the data in the following way:

```
{-1,0;0,2.5;1,5}
```

But for some reasons it does not change in the right way.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12mLomA5RaZbU4WworyzljCSRGgn6cuBnojMOU4HqT2o/edit?usp=sharing

Best regards,
Hanna

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, your range only goes from -1 but you have two 'Clicks Delta' values of -12 and -26, therefore the vlookup is out of range.

Change the range from:

`{-1,0;0,2.5;1,5}`

to:

`{-1000,0;0,2.5;1,5}`